# keyframes creating issue when using with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to create bubble and also bubble burst on click.I am using two keyframes, One for bubbling, and other is when click on bubble.

Problem is when I click on bubble the effect is showing on wrong areas. Here is my code sample. i can't understand where is the issue is

because of two keyframes timing is wrong. how to adjust click effect where the bubble is exactly click.

```js
$('.bubbles li').on('click',mouseremove, function () {
        const thisBubble = $(this);
        thisBubble.addClass('bubble-pop');
        setTimeout(() => {
            thisBubble.hide();
             mouseremove(thisBubble);
        }, 500);
    });

    function mouseremove(thisBubble) {
        thisBubble.removeClass('bubble-pop');
       setTimeout(() => {
           thisBubble.show();
       }, 500);
     }
```

```css
.bubbles {
  padding:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.bubbles li {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://www.fundacioarcadi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/bombolla-01.png');
  background-size: 20px;
  bottom: -100px;
  -webkit-animation: square 40s infinite ;
  animation: square 40s infinite ;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  
}
li{
  background-image: url("https://www.fundacioarcadi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/bombolla-01.png");
  background-size: cover !important;
}



.bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  left: 10%;
}
.bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 40%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-duration: 60s;
}

.bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 60%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-duration: 60s;
}

.bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  left: 80%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 45s;
  animation-duration: 45s;
}

.bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 35s;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

.bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 65s;
  animation-duration: 65s;
}

.bubbles li:nth-child(7) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 90%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
  animation-delay: 45s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-duration: 30s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes square {
  0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
      transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-1080px);
      transform: translateY(-1080px);
  }
}

@keyframes square {
  0% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
      transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-1080px) rotate(180deg);
      transform: translateY(-1080px) rotate(180deg);
  }
}


.bubble-pop {
  -webkit-animation: bubblePop 0.4s ease !important;
  -moz-animation: bubblePop 0.4s ease  !important;
  animation: bubblePop 0.4s ease  !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes bubblePop {
  0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
  opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes bubblePop {
  0% {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
  opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  }
  }
  @keyframes bubblePop {
  0% {
  transform: scale(0.2);
  opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
  transform: scale(0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bubbles">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: PS... there's no need to -vendor-prefix animation keyframes since are supported by all major browsers.

Comment: when click on bubble @Roko   click on bubble you will see the issue

Comment: yes, I've maximised the example and the issue is much more visible!

Comment: PS: you should also set `padding: 0;` to your UL element...

Comment: no changes after adding padding : 0 ;

Comment: I know, it was a "PS". The reason your CSS animations don't work as intended is because you cannot stack/merge AKA **interpolate** CSS `animation` transforms. As soon you set a new `animation` property to your element, the previous animation gets canceled and the element transform is reset to its original position.

Comment: do you have any solution of it